# Is It Possible To Migrate From Realm To Sqlite?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, realm, database-migration

For some reasons(mainly large apk size even with ABI splits, anyway) i need to remove Realm completely and use Sqlite without losing data.

I couldn't find a way. It seems the app must continue using Realm, or users will lost their data completely.

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: Please see my answer below and consider closing the question if the answer satisfies you

Comment: Realm is the only thing that can open the Realm file, and your migration from Realm to SQLite would need both at the same time (to prevent data loss).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Woefully, this is answer of this question, thanks.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Also i'm wondering this, okay, let's assume we removed Realm and user received new version of app. What about the Realm files ? They will be stored as garbage until user clearing the app data or uninstalling app?

Comment: Well unless you delete them yourself.... They're Just files though, so you can do that. To clear Realm files, you can look at the implementation for `Realm.deleteFile()` I think that's what it was called.

Comment: But i'm removing Realm, so how can i use `Realm.deleteFile()`?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think I understand fully what your problem is. If you are asking if there is a tool that will automate the data migration for you, then no, there is no such a tool.

Otherwise it is rather straight forward:

1. Handle `onCreate`, `onDowngrade` and `onUpgrade` methods in the implementation of your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.
2. In your `onCreate` method, right after you create tables, get all your data from **Realm** and insert into into SQLite tables.

Something like this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
RealmResults<MyClass> all = realm.where(MyClass.class)
                                 .findAll();
for (MyClass instance : all) {
    doInsert(instance);
}
```

I actually suggest that you look into [how to reduce APK size](https://news.realm.io/news/reducing-apk-size-native-libraries/) while using Realm, but it is up to you

**EDIT 1**
You would have to make sure that you migrate the data first and then delete Realm files. Although it is not the data files that make your APK big, but rather the actual libraries that come with Realm. So for this you will, unfortunately, have to take two steps: first release update that migrates the data to SQLite, and after some reasonable time (like a week) you can release update that takes Realm libraries completely out. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for helpful response but the question is clear and says "i need to remove Realm completely and use Sqlite without losing data." In my next app update the Realm will be removed exactly, so the code above will not work. @EpicPandaForce's comment is just what did i want to learn

Comment: "have to take two steps: first release update that migrates the data to SQLite, and after some reasonable time (like a week) you can release update that takes Realm libraries completely out" This seems the most relevant way for me(but bad), thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider closing the question as answered.

Comment: @Blackkara For this to work it actually requires that the users would update their app twice, which you can't be certain of. Not all users choose to update to every version. They could easily skip or miss the first upgrade or more and then upgrade later, in which case they would not have they files upgraded.

Comment: That is correct, however, you can never be certain that all users have performed an update. I've frequently see users that are still behind in updating my apps by several month. This will always be 'best-effort' scenario and never 100%. If the goal is to reduce apk size while preserving user data it is quite reasonable to assume that about 99% of users that actually use the app will complete an update in a week's timeframe

Answer (score 1):

As i know (not sure) if you are using default RealmConfig, `Context.getFilesDir()` can return the folder of where default.realm is located. You dont need permission to modify them. You can iterate files under this folder to delete them. Hope it works.

PS : Apache-commons has a great FileUtils.java

Good luck

Emre