# Migrate from Realm to Sqlite

Tags: android, realm, android-room

I started my app using `Realm` as it seemed the most convenient way of storing data back then.

The realm has two big drawbacks for me at the moment:

- APK Size: Realm libs add a lot to the APK size. I'm using currently App Bundles to minimize the impact, still, this is an issue compared to `SQLite` (my use-case is pretty simple, don't need advanced features)
- Compatibility with App bundles: As I started using app bundles to overcome the above issue another one rose and is still present: [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3484)

Therefore I want to go back to plain `SQLite` (maybe using `Room`).

Thing is, in order to "migrate" I'd need to have both in parallel for quite some time to migrate all existing users.

The plan would be:

1. Create data structures for `Room`
2. Have an upgrade mechanism which takes all Realm tables a fills `Room` tables
3. Only use `Room` data structures in the app
4. Release App Version X
5. At some point remove Realm from the app (can only be done, once 99% of users are on app version X)

I guess there's no other way around or has anybody already faced the same issue?

Comment: Realm libs add a lot to the APK size - how much size?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is It Possible To Migrate From Realm To Sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44208967/is-it-possible-to-migrate-from-realm-to-sqlite)

Comment: @PavelPoley if you do not use split APKs it was nearly 7MB of native libs

Answer (score 0):

I'm on the same situation right now.

### Current idea

I'd say your plan with steps 1-5 would be an **in-app/local database migration** from **Realm to SQLite**. And it has all the considerations about user adoption of the right version(s) for the database migration to work for users (100%).

I'm considering another option. **A web service**. (*Please bear with me as I didn't implement this solution yet, I'm still on the considerations/planning phase*).

If on budget, how about to setup a web service to carry on with the database migration on app's behalf?

### On-line Database Migration

Something along these lines:

1. Update your app to run with *SQLite* only (remove everything about *Realm*);
2. Your updated app, at start, detects if it has a *SQLite* database or not;
3. If no *SQLite* database detected, app checks for *Realm* database;
4. If a *Realm* database file is found, file is sent to your web service for migration to *SQLite*, sent back to the app and installed accordingly;
5. Resume from newly updated *SQLite* database file;
6. If no *SQLite* and *Realm* database files are found, create the *SQLite* as *Realm* never existed;

### Considerations

- Data transfer, hosting and processing costs (serverless/lambda services are an option? A microservice?);
- Concurrency at the web service side (how many users would need this service concurrently?);
- User's privacy (any breakage of user's privacy, terms of service, privacy policy?);
- Security for both transfer and storage (if you plan to have any sort of rollback plan);
- Is the *Realm* database encrypted? How to deal with it?
- How long do we keep the web service for database migration on-line?
- Do we keep the *Realm* file on the device if something goes wrong?
- Any specific logging requirements for this task?
- Do we need to be compliant to any standard or practice?

### Epilogue

As mentioned, I didn't implement such solution yet, so I can't provide insights about practicalities yet (I shall update this answer if I follow this path).

I have a feeling that this on-line database migration approach has as its main advantage that we off load the app from the database migration; on the other hand, it adds considerable complexity to a task that is already risky.

Finally, another possibility I can think of right now would be to migrate the database totally on-line, *Firebase-ish* or reachable trough a web API. But I believe this path don't match the scenario I could deduce from your question.

Would love to hear from community as well.

Best of luck.